# PHP: Array index value ordering

Tags: php

**I need to change my array index values from**

```
 Array ( [0] => 84 [1] => 109 [4] => 78 )
```

**to**

```
  Array ( [1] => 84 [2] => 109 [3] => 78 )
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty method

```
$arrayData = array_combine(
    range(1, count($arrayData)),
    $arrayData
);
```

Comment: Thank you it works!!, but typo error.. you missed an bracket!!

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to re-index starting to zero, simply do the following:**

```
$ArrayFromZero = array_values($arr);
```

**If you need it to start at one, then use the following:**

```
$arrayFromOne = array_combine(range(1, count($arr)), array_values($arr));
```